# Where to learn about "analog prototype filters"?

Tags: filter-design

Where to learn about "analog prototype filters"?

I've heard about them, but I'm unsure about what they really are and how they're constructed.

Comment: Do you want op-amp circuits?  The Audio EQ Cookbook will give your $H(s)$ transfer functions for standard second-order analog filters.  But if you want circuits, start with the Sallen-Key.  Google that.  Also there is an EE stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

"Analog prototype" filters are well-known analog filters that have specific desirable properties. They include (but aren't limited to):

- [Butterworth filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter): maximally-flat passband response
- [Chebyshev filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter): sharper rolloff than Butterworth, equiripple in either the passband or stopband
- [Elliptic filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_filter): even sharper rolloff, equiripple in passband and stopband
- [Bessel filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_filter): maximally-flat group delay

These prototypes can be used to design digital filters that have approximately the same characteristics, for instance by using the [bilinear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform).

Comment: Why are they called analog?

Comment: Because they are physical objects that operate on [analog signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_signal).

Comment: How? The Wikipedia page e.g. just gives a formula for a Butterworth LPF. Surely it can be realized in many ways, e.g. digitally. So what makes it analog? Perhaps it's some thing about "frequency" being analogue without Fourier transforms or something?

Comment: Note that for the Bessel filter, the bilinear transform will not result in a discrete-time filter that is optimal in any sense, because the frequency warping will affect the maximally flat group delay property. All other analog filters mentioned in this answer will retain their optimality when transformed by the bilinear transform.

Comment: @mavavilj they are “analog” in the sense that one can implement the filter in the continuous time domain (via design using Laplace transforms) using analog electronic components (resistors, inductors, capacitors), rather than discrete digital filters using the Z-transform. See Matt L.’s response regarding the bilinear transform as it’s a very important thing to note.

Comment: Also resist the temptation to design a digital filter by copying an analog prototype (unless there is specific reason to do so, such as modelling an analog system). In most cases direct digital filter design algorithms will result in the best filter implementation. Analog is limited by the realizable components (inductors, capacitors etc) while digital is limited by the math and precision available. This holds true for many aspects of signal processing design where a relationship to a known analog process can be instructive, but be cautious in simply copying an analog implementation.

Comment: @mavavilj Note that historically, analog filter theory was mostly developed in the 1920's-1930's for analog telecommunications circuits; digital filters weren't designed until about the 1960's; by that point standard analog filter topologies had been developed and were very familiar to the community.

Comment: *//Also resist the temptation to design a digital filter by copying an analog prototype//*  Actually, @DanBoschen, it can go both ways.  You can design a "optimal" finite-order IIR digital filter using, say Prony or Greg Berchin's FDLS or Matt L's method and use Bilinear to transform that $H(z)$ to an $H(s)$ and build the damn thing with resistors, capacitors, op-amps, and perhaps inductors.  But sometimes, particularly in an application where aesthetic is valuable, a good-ol' Butterworth or Tchebyshev Type 2 is just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yes very true. I’ve just seen many cases where it is misused because one thought mapping in general is best

Answer (score 0):

In the domain of digital audio effects, analog filters (called analog prototype filters or analog prototypes) are used to derive **stable and controllable** digital infinite-impulse response (IIR) filters.

These filters can then be used by musicians or sound engineers, for example, in parametric equalizers.

[image: Creating parametric equalizer filters involves the analog prototype design]

If you are interested in the topic, I have a few materials that extend the topic:

1. What is an analog prototype filter and how to design it [article](https://www.thewolfsound.com/analog-prototype/) [video](https://youtu.be/rrMRkPpRQAs)
2. How to digitize the analog prototype with the bilinear transform [article](https://www.thewolfsound.com/bilinear-transform/)